# Extract different numbers from multiple strings

Tags: excel, vba, string

In a .csv spreadsheet, I have multiple strings with incrementing numerical values contained in each, and I need to extract the numbers from each string. For example, here are two strings:

```
DEVICE1.CM1 - 4.1.1.C1.CA_VALUE (A)
DEVICE1.CM2 - 6.7.1.C2.CA_VALUE (A)
DEVICE1.CM1 - 4.1.2.C1.CA_VALUE (A) 
DEVICE1.CM1 - 4.1.2.C2.CA_VALUE (A) 
DEVICE1.CM1 - 4.1.2.C3.CA_VALUE (A) 
DEVICE1.CM1 - 5.1.1.C1.CA_VALUE (A) 
DEVICE1.CM1 - 5.1.1.C2.CA_VALUE (A) 
DEVICE1.CM1 - 5.10.1.C3.CA_VALUE (A) 
DEVICE1.CM1 - 6.13.1.C10.CA_VALUE (A)
```

And I am looking to extract "4.1.1.C1" from the first string, and "6.7.1.C2" from the second string.

I have over 1000 strings, each with a different incremental value in the form of "#.#.#.C.#" and all of the options I have tried so far involve searching for a specific value to extract, rather than extracting all values of that general form. Is there any reasonable way to accomplish this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Comment: Two pieces of data isn't quite enough to come up with a reliable method. Are the values always preceded by "  - " and followed by "_VALUE"?

Comment: Use mid() with find() to get the " - " and " _ ". Then copy paste values.

Comment: Yes, they are always preceeded by " - " and followed by ".CA_VALUE (A)".
Here are some more examples: 
DEVICE1.CM1 - 4.1.2.C1.CA_VALUE (A)
DEVICE1.CM1 - 4.1.2.C2.CA_VALUE (A)
DEVICE1.CM1 - 4.1.2.C3.CA_VALUE (A)
DEVICE1.CM1 - 5.1.1.C1.CA_VALUE (A)
DEVICE1.CM1 - 5.1.1.C2.CA_VALUE (A)
DEVICE1.CM1 - 5.10.1.C3.CA_VALUE (A)
DEVICE1.CM1 - 6.13.1.C10.CA_VALUE (A)

Let me know if I can provide any more details that would help.

Comment: You could also use PowerQuery for this. Load your csv, transform data and load into Excel.

Comment: As @SolarMike said, use a combination of `FIND` and `MID` to get the middle of the string. If your text is in cell A1 try `=MID(A1,FIND(" - ",A1,1)+3,FIND("_",A1,FIND(" - ",A1,1))-FIND(" - ",A1,1)-6)`.

Answer (score 3):

I am not a big fan of regular expressions because they are often hard to read, but this is a typical example where you should use them. Read carefully the Q&A BigBen linked to in the comments.

```
Function extractCode(s As String) As String
    Static rx As RegExp
    If rx Is Nothing Then Set rx = New RegExp
    rx.Pattern = "\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.C\d"
    If rx.Test(s) Then
        extractCode = rx.Execute(s)(0)
    End If
End Function
```

(You will need to add the reference to the Microsoft VBScript Regular Expression library)

--> Updated my answer, you need to escape the dot, else it is a placeholder for *any* character and the pattern would also match something like "4x1y2zC3",

Comment: I'm quite a newb when it comes to regex. What do you think about `\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.C\d+`? Isn't dot without a preceding backslash just any character? I've been playing with it [here](https://regex101.com/r/Tve6J2/1).

Comment: @VBasic2008 You are right. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

So here goes:
[image]

```
MID(A1,FIND("-",A1,1)+2,(FIND("_",A1,1)-FIND("-",A1,1))-5)
```

Answer (score 1):

The fixed structure

> *(items) are always preceeded by " - " and followed by ".CA_VALUE (A)"*

allows to isolate the code string via `Split` as follows:

- consider `".CA_VALUE (A)"` as closing delimiter, but change occurrence(s) to `"- "`
- execute `Split` now on the resulting string using only the first delimiter (`StartDelim` `"- "`)
- isolate the second token (index: `1` as split results are zero-based)

```
Function ExtractCode(ByVal s As String) As String
    Const StartDelim   As String = "- "
    Const ClosingDelim As String = ".CA_VALUE (A)"
    ExtractCode = Split(Replace(s, ClosingDelim, StartDelim), StartDelim)(1)
End Function
```

---

**Another approach with focus on splitting via point delimiters** *//Edit 2021-11-20*

If you want to *experiment* with a **fixed start position** of your 4-items code in a split array (based on point delimiters `"."`),
you might also consider the following approach:

- split via point delimiters `"."`
- filter only the 3rd,4th,5th and 6th item via `WorksheetFunction.Index` (by its columns argument)
- join the resulting items again via connecting points `"."`

**a) Using (Excel) version MS 365**

```
Function ExtractCode(ByVal s As String, Optional startPos As Long = 3) As Variant
    Const delim As String = "."
    Dim tmp
    tmp = Split(Replace(s, "- ", delim), delim)   ' normalize hyphen to point delimiter
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        ExtractCode = Join(.Index(tmp, 0, .Sequence(1, 4, startPos)), ".")
    End With
End Function
```

**b) Make it backwards compatible**

Just change the function result assignment to

```
        ExtractCode = Join(.Index(tmp, 0, Evaluate("{1,2,3,4}-1+" & startPos)), ".")
```

which in both cases changes the `Index` column argument to a 1-based column number `Array(3,4,5,6)`